# How to only remove one item from list with duplicates?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have a list: `(x, y, y,z)`

I have another list: `(x, y)`

You want to remove the items from the 1st list that belong also in the 2nd list.

Ex: I want the result to be `(y,z)`

**How do I do this?**

***EDIT:*** If I use removeAll. The example list returns (z)

Comment: You want to remove the items from the 1st list that belong also in the 2nd list. Edit your question.

Comment: Does order matter? For example, if the second list was (y, x) would you want the same outcome?

Comment: The result will be (z) not (y,z)

Comment: Guys, its simple. I don't want it to remove y twice.

Comment: And the result is z

Comment: Are the two list sorted?

Comment: is that important?

Comment: No very important. It is much simpler if the lists are sorted, just iterate the two list only once, time complexity is O(length of two list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems acceptable.

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
one.add("x");
one.add("y");
one.add("y");
one.add("z");
List<String> two = new ArrayList<>();
two.add("x");
two.add("y");

for (String s : two)
{
    one.remove(s);
}

System.out.println("one : " + one);
```

The output :

> one : [y, z]

---

[List.remove(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) documentation :

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

---

**Note**: The algorithm complexity is `O(n*m)`, avoid to do it with 2 very big lists (where `n` and `m` are list size).

Comment: I tried the answer but It didn't work. I will try the comment.

Comment: You can also use lambda `two.forEach(one::remove);` but less readable in my opinion, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Here is some examples.

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();
    one.add("x");
    one.add("y");
    one.add("y");
    one.add("z");
List<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();
    two.add("x");
    two.add("y");
```

**1. Using Lambda**

```
two.forEach((i)->one.remove(i));
System.out.println(one);
```

Output: [y, z]

**2. Apache Commons**

```
Collection<Integer> result = CollectionUtils.subtract(one, two);
System.out.println(one);
```

Output: [y, z]

Comment: If I removeAll. The example list returns (z)

Comment: You can try again. I have added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("Maria");
    list1.add("Nick");
    list1.add("Nick");
    list1.add("Joe");

    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("Maria");
    list2.add("Nick");

    for (String x : list2) {
        int index = list1.indexOf(x);
        if (index >= 0) {
            list1.remove(index);
        }
    }
```